# Swagger + spring boot + jwt + How to disable Authorize button for specific API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, bearer-token

I have configured JWT Bearer token authentication in my spring boot application. I have "Authenticate" and "Hello" controllers where in "Hello" controller takes in Bearer token as Authorization header. "Authenticate" api generates the bearer token. Everything works fine with postman. But from swagger side, I am not able to disable "Authorize" button for "Authenticate" api.
[swagger screen clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kOGw.png)

Here with my code looks like:
SwaggerConfig file:

```
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringfoxDocket() {
        Contact contact = new Contact(
                "shivaraj",
                "https://shivaraj.co",
                "bmxxxxx@xxxx.com");

        List<VendorExtension> vext = new ArrayList<>();
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "Backend API",
                "description",
                "1.0.0",
                "https://shivaraj.co",
                contact,
                "MIT",
                "https://shivaraj.co",
                vext);

        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo)
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(ApiInfo.DEFAULT)
                .forCodeGeneration(true)
                .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                .ignoredParameterTypes(SpringDataWebProperties.Pageable.class)
                .ignoredParameterTypes(java.sql.Date.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(java.time.LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(java.time.ZonedDateTime.class, Date.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(java.time.LocalDateTime.class, Date.class)
                .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);

        docket = docket.select()
                .paths(regex(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN))
                .build();

        return docket;
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN))
                .build();
    }

    List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
                = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Lists.newArrayList(
                new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }
```

As alternate approach, is there a way we can enable authorization button in swagger for each individual controller?

Comment: Got it resoled by myself. Just for others: adding "security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")" to @Operation tag allowed enabling/disabling token authentication.

Answer (score 0):

adding `security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")` to `@Operation` tag allowed enabling/disabling token authentication.